# Macports download of gcc hangs

Tags: macports

Just as the title says - I'm trying to get the newest `gcc` on my Mac (Yosemite) using Macports. I tested other commands to make sure Macports is working - ex. "port search gcc" works for me.

so, I go to type "`sudo port install gcc5`" - nothing happens. I try "`sudo port install gcc_select`" (after seeing this suggested on an answer to a different question on this site) - nothing happens. If I use "top" I see that xcode is very busy doing SOMETHING related to what I have typed, but I let my computer sit ~ 10 minutes and there is no text or anything telling me that Macports is actually doing something...

Help please! I'm a previous Windows user and all of this is very much over my head. I have no idea what could possibly be wrong and I haven't seen this asked anywhere.

Comment: Try with `sudo port -d install gcc5`; that may give you a hint on what's wrong. Also, mention your OS X version, your Xcode version and the result of `xcode-select -print-path`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My OS version is 10.10.5, the result of " xcode-select -print-path " is just "/" and the xcode version is 7.1

I can't paste all of it (word count too long) but here is where " sudo port -d install gcc5 " hangs:
DEBUG: Reading variant descriptions from /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/_resources/port1.0/variant_descriptions.conf

Comment: I think your value for `xcode-select -print-path` should be something in `/Applications/Xcode`, but I cannot check at the moment because I'm not at my Mac. Maybe somebody else has the required data.